# FactoryBot: Why is an association not working (can't be blank)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have three FactoryBot factories for my Rails project. If I test the factory validities with FactoryBot.lint, the book factory is not valid - as per this error. Am I doing something wrong?

```
Book format can't be blank
```

book.rb factory:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :book do
    title { 'The Hobbit' }
    book_format
    owner
  end
end
```

book_format.rb factory:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :book_format do
    name { 'default' }
  end
end
```

owner.rb factory:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :owner do
    email { 'john@doe.com' }
    password { 'password'}
  end
end
```

EDIT: Realized I forgot to add code from models - here it is:

Relevant code from book model:

```
  belongs_to :book_format, counter_cache: true
  belongs_to :owner, counter_cache: true
```

Relevant code from book_format model:

```
  has_many :books
```

Relevant code from owner model:

```
  has_many :books, dependent: :destroy
```

I don't understand why I am getting this error message on book_format - and not on owner (that would also be weird but at least consistent?).

2nd EDIT:
This works:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :book do
    title { 'The Hobbit' }
    owner
    book_format { BookFormat.create( name: 'default' ) }
  end
end
```

Comment: Does the BookFormat model have any other required fields?  Is your database set up correctly for the books and book_formats tables?

Comment: The BookFormat factory works. And in dev / prod, everything works fine, as well as when I create the BookFormat manually in tests. Just the book factory for some reason not accepting the BookForm factory...

Comment: just curious, what happens if you move the book_format and owner factories inside the same `define` block for `book`? and another question, what happens if you add `optional: true` to the book_format belongs to? does it then fail with the owner association?

Comment: moving the book_format factory into the same define block doesn't change anything. If I create the format within the book factory, it works - see 2nd edit to my question above. Could this be a simple "naming" thing (BookFormat, book_format etc etc...?)

Answer (score 0):

You can create `BookFormat` with factory bot and later you won't need get to book factory and add new fields which may appear in `BookFormat` model:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :book do
    title { 'The Hobbit' }
    owner
    book_format { FactoryBot.create(:book_format) }
  end
end
```

Comment: I am not sure I follow what you mean?

Comment: In example, you add new field 'some_field' to book_format, now you need to go to book_format factroy and add this field in it and then you need to go to book factroy and add this new field from book_format to this factroy. But if you using FactroyBot.create instead of BookFormat.create then you don't need to go to book factory and add new field from book_format

Comment: So the point I am not getting is: Why can I create an owner implicitely by simply calling "owner" in the book factory - this automatically invokes the factory :owner and all is good. But the same doesn't work for book_format?